# Output of C via Sublime Text / closing the command console

Tags: c, shell, command-line, sublimetext3

I'm new to compiling/running C scripts via Sublime Text 3, and I have a question on the output. My build in C is currently:

```
{
"cmd": ["gcc", "-Wall", "-ansi", "-pedantic-errors", "$file_name", "-o",     "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k" , "$file_base_name"],
"selector": "source.c",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"shell": true
}
```

This works great, but it opens a new Windows cmd console everytime I run a script. Two questions:

1 - I am used to editing Python in Sublime Text, and running a script via the command line as: `python prognam.py`. How can I do this with C? I have the MinGW path set in my PATH environment variables, so I'd think it would be similar.

2 - Is it possible to edit my build script such that a new command console does not pop up every time?

Comment: <s>C (as said in your question and tags) or C++ (as in the title)?</s> Nevermind, probably not that important for your question.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm pretty new to C/C++ altogether -- I don't know the difference well enough to answer.  My background is in MATLAB and Python.

Comment: Have no idea about Sublime Text, but I would try to change `"shell": true` to `"shell": false`

Comment: Or, more likely, replace the `/k` switch to `/c`

Comment: @EugeneSh., I tried that -- for some reason, I get an error from other things, that I can post if necessary.  Changing `/k` to `/c` closes the command window, but my printed solution also closes w/ the command window. I would like to see the output of my program for sanity checking.

Comment: So you have some conflicting requirements, don't you? You want the window to close, but don't want it to close.

Comment: I suppose that's true, but it seems like I should be able to have both -- like the solution being printed in the SublimeText compiler output window, that tells me the script completion time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was eventually solved -- the output, and the time elapsed for the script is shown in the bottom of the Sublime Text window as illustrated. The steps I took before it was solved were as follows:

- Use MinGW to install all C and C++ compiling packages.
- Using Sublime Text 3's "C++ Single File" build system.

[image]